# How can I set a number for a public variable at userforms in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I write  `public X as integer` and then `X=2`. But when I run it, there is an error. what do I write?

```
Public b as Integer

b=2

Private Sub exa_Click()

range("A" & 3)=b

End Sub
```

I do not know what can I do

Comment: Do you ever want to change the value of b from 2

Comment: @CDP1802 yes. I want to change it when it is necessary

Comment: `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize():  b = 2: End Sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is setting the variable outside of the subroutine.

Try:

```
Public b As Integer

Private Sub exa_Click()

b = 2

Range("A" & 3) = b

End Sub
```

Comment: But  I want to change the value of b (for all macro userforms) when it is necessary

Comment: You can, just change it inside of a subroutine.

Comment: only for one subroutine? So there is no way that we can set a number for a variable that we use this variable in several button of a userform? is there?

Comment: The value changes globally, so you can access it wherever.